# .Net Database how do I properly close my database connections?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database-connection

So I've read a lot about SqlDataReaders not being disposed of properly in .Net - and I've been fighting the "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached" error for a couple days now.  Obviously I could jack the max pool size up to 30,000 - but that doesn't address the actual problem.

As I step through the code, I execute the following SQL Query:

```
select * from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
where counter_name ='User Connections'
```

After the

```
cmd.Connection.Open();
```

line, the User Connections are incremented by 1.  However, it NEVER goes back down unless I recycle the app pool on the web server (at which point all active database connections from the website are killed).

Here is my code:

```
public static DataTable SPExecuteDataTable(string[] ConnectionData, params object[] args)
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlDataReader dr = null;
    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionData[1]);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(ConnectionData[0], new SqlConnection(ConnectionData[1]));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            SqlParameter Param = new SqlParameter(ConnectionData[i + 2], DBNullIfNull(args[i]));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Param);
        }

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr != null)
                dt.Load(dr);
            else
                dt = null;
        }

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Exception x = new Exception(String.Format("DataAccess.SPExecuteDataTable() {0}", e.Message));
        throw x;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        dr.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        dr.Dispose();
    }
```

So far, I've tried explicitly closing the connections (like in my finally block), but that doesn't work.  I've also tried using statements like so:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = blah blah blah)
{
    //code here
}
```

But that also doesn't work.  What is wrong with my code, here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Use DataTables!  To prevent having non-data-access layers of your application from having to communicate with the database, just do this in your data-access layer:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (dr != null)
                                dt.Load(dr);
                            else
                                dt = null;
                        }
                        return dt;
```

Then, you can manipulate the dt however you'd like in the rest of your solution, and the connections HAVE ALREADY BEEN properly disposed.  Works like a charm and, luckily, the code for a datatable and datareader are very similar, so modifying the application in this manner was relatively painless.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred practice is to wrap connections, commands, and readers in `using` blocks:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionData[1])
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConnectionData[0], conn)
    {                                                     // ^-- re-use connection - see comment below
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            SqlParameter Param = new SqlParameter(ConnectionData[i + 2], DBNullIfNull(args[i]));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Param);
        }

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr != null)
                dt.Load(dr);
            else
                dt = null;
        }

        return dt;
    }    
}
```

that way they all get closed and disposed of properly.

Although I think the heart of your issue is that you're creating *two* connections each time:

```
conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionData[1]);
cmd = new SqlCommand(ConnectionData[0], new SqlConnection(ConnectionData[1]));
                                        ^----  creating a second connection
```

Finally, you are losing a lot of potentially valuable information (stack trace, etc.) by creating a new exception and throwing it rather than re-throwing the original exception:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Exception x = new Exception(String.Format("DataAccess.SPExecuteDataTable() {0}", e.Message));
    throw x;
}
```

I would either let the original exception bubble up or include the original exception as the `InnerException`:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    string message = String.Format("DataAccess.SPExecuteDataTable() {0}", e.Message);
    Exception x = new Exception(message, e);
    throw x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out.  To clarify, the redundant connections (end of your post) was not the original setup.  I changed TO that when troubleshooting the problem.  I just changed the cmd = line of code and replaced "new sqlcon..." with "conn" - and the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks a lot - still testing this out...Also, can you explain how you would return a SqlDataReader from a function while using your nested using statements?  Would they still self-dispose?

Comment: You would not put it in a using if you are returning it. In that pattern it is the responsibility of the caller to dispose of the reader, which is why returning readers is not a best practice - it separates the responsibility of creating the object from disposing of it.

Comment: While this hasn't completely solved the problem, it has greatly diminished it.  The connections are still piling up, albeit much less than before.  Any idea why some of the connections would still persist, given the code you've posted?

Comment: @Stan Not without knowing what's in `ConnectionData[1]`.  Connections are pooled, so as long as your connection string doesn't change you shouldn't by leaking connections.

Comment: Here is a sample connection string.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Data Source=xxx.xxx.x.xxx;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserID;Password=Password;Connection Timeout=60; Max Pool Size=5000;

Comment: And the connection strings are constants within the solution, so they won't change.

Comment: You could try dropping the Max Pool Size - the default is 100.